# Book to learn Winforms Controls

Tags: .net

I'm new to .NET and Winforms. I have a lot of experience with C++ but I would like to learn more about the individual controls available with .NET.

What's the best book that would show the use of the various controls that can be used with WinForms (like progress bar, status bar, etc)

Thanks to you all in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book Recommendation for Winforms Design & Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357545/book-recommendation-for-winforms-design-programming)

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Forms Programming in C# book by Chris Sells](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321116208) is a good one.  There is a lot of information in there, including a list of controls based on general control type (Lists, containers, etc), and describes how to work with the different classes of controls.  There is also an appendix for folks moving from MFC (which you may or may not be doing).

Comment: I can also recommend the "newer version" in your link; excellent WinForms coverage.

Comment: Heh, didn't even check the edition on the amazon page.  Just did a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

This one: http://www.charlespetzold.com/winforms/

Previously, Charlez Petzold had a totally remarkable book in Windows programming. This makes me think this one should also be good, although I never read it (even despite buying it).